# How to linarize only a part of a XML file?

Tags: xml, editing

I am struggling with a huge XML file (size over 400M) and I would need to linarize only parts of it. I have tried editing it with Notepad++ and XML Tools plugin, but it will linarize everything. As English is not my native language, maybe an example will make things more clear.

I want this:

```
<Example>
    <Data>
        <First>abcd</First>
        <Second>efgh</Second>
        <Third>ijkl</Third>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Fourth>mnop</Fourth>
        <Fifth>qrst</Fifth>
        <Sixth>uvwx</Sixth>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Seventh>1234</Seventh>
        <Eigth>5678</Eigth>
        <Ninth>90ab</Ninth>
    </Data>
</Example>
```

To be printed out like this:

```
<Example>
    <Data><First>abcd</First><Second>efgh</Second><Third>ijkl</Third></Data>
    <Data><Fourth>mnop</Fourth><Fifth>qrst</Fifth><Sixth>uvwx</Sixth></Data>
    <Data><Seventh>1234</Seventh><Eigth>5678</Eigth><Ninth>90ab</Ninth></Data>
</Example>
```

Any ideas? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: XML parsers don't really give you the control you're looking for.  You might try XSL, with text output, and manually build psuedo elements from the real elements.  Seriously though, why on earth would you ever print out that much data...

Comment: Why do you need to linarize part of this, make no sense. I would suggest that you use Xpath to grab a subset, or persist it into a db f.ex.. But your intent is not clear here.

Answer (score 1):

Your example simply removes some of the whitespace: is that all that you need to do?

With a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformer you can achieve the example transformation using:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="Data"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="deep-copy"/>
</xsl:transform>
```